# Do C# classes inherit constructors?

Tags: c#

I just read http://blog.gurock.com/articles/creating-custom-exceptions-in-dotnet/

I don't know when it is written. It says:

"Since C# unfortunately doesn’t inherit constructors of base classes, this new type only has the standard constructor with no parameters and is therefore relatively useless."

This says the same in 2010: [C#: inheriting constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873343/c-inheriting-constructors)

Is this still true?

EDIT: Following on from answers, I'm sure there would be a way around the default parameterless constructor. Are there other reasons for lack of constructor inheritance?

Comment: It's still true (and it's still true for C++ and Java too ;) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426484/why-are-constructors-not-inherited for some discussion.

Comment: Take a look at the spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Constructors have never been inheritable in the entire lifetime of the C# language. That hasn't changed in C# 5.0: at the end of section 1.6.7.1 of the C# 5.0 spec, it still says:

> Unlike other members, instance constructors are not inherited, and a class has no instance constructors other than those actually declared in the class. If no instance constructor is supplied for a class, then an empty one with no parameters is automatically provided.

So it still holds true today, and I imagine it will remain so in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Perhaps mention you can access the constructor in the base class explicitly, as that's a solution many will be looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You have to explicitly call the constructor of the base class, unless the base class defines a default constructor. So yes they are not inherited.

Which sometimes lead to a bunch of boiler plate code where you do nothing than pass arguments from one constructor to another

```
public class NegativArgument : Exception {
     public NegativeArgument() : this("The number given was less than zero"){}
     public NegativeArgument(string message) : this(message,null){}
     public NegativeArgument(string message, Exception inner) : base:(message,inner){}
}
```

but what if you had an Exception type that should always have the same message? how would you solve that if the constructors were inherited? The exception class has a constructor that accepts a message so creating a new Exception type would in that case get that constructor too, not inheriting constructors makes it easy

```
public class NegativArgument : Exception {
     public NegativeArgument() : base("The number given was less than zero"){}
}
```

If the base class does not have a default constructor you will have a compile error if you do not explicitly call a base class constructor.

Comment: I think Delphi gets round the latter problem by having classes with lots of protected members; these classes are not supposed to be instantiated. Descendants can raise the visibility of members for use.

Comment: @cja just as you can expose a construtor from a base class. The syntax is in the first example :)

Comment: I am creating a custom Exception and found myself redefining the constructors on derive classes. google brought me here. I guess I dont have a choice but to redefine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should call them explicitly the constructor of the base classes. They are not *inheritable*.

Didn't change anything about them.

Check out : [`Constructors (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx)

From the spec §1.6.7.1:

> Unlike other members, instance constructors are not inherited, and a
>   class has no instance constructors other than those actually declared
>   in the class. If no instance constructor is supplied for a class, then
>   an empty one with no parameters is automatically provided.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are not inherited in C#.

If they were, then *every* class would have a default parameterless constructor (because all classes derive from Object and Object has a default parameterless constructor).

Many classes should only be constructed with specific values; this would be impossible to ensure if every class had a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: I'm sure there would be a way around the default parameterless constructor. Are there other reasons for lack of constructor inheritance?

Comment: There's no nice way around it.

Comment: Yes - you make it private. But then it's not available to anything outside the class.

Comment: Then why does the excerpt pasted by @boltclock say the exact opposite?  ```If no instance constructor is supplied for a class, then an empty one with no parameters is automatically provided.```

Comment: @BrianVPS Supplying a default constructor isn't the same as inheriting one.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon the section "Constructors are not inherited" near the bottom of [this entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513153007/https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/constructors.html) on Jon Skeet's blog.

#### Summary

There are many cases in which a derived class may require information beyond that contained in the base class. Jon gives the example of the `FileInfo` class which requires additional information to be well-defined. Namely, that of the file for which info is to be provided

Any suggested 'fix' for this would entail overriding things in a way that prevents constructing such derived objects using the inherited constructors. However, knowingly requiring derived classes to override their base classes in a way that makes them more restrictive goes against best practice. (see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184910) for Jon's discussion of the Liskov Substitution principle and the importance of being able to use derived classes wherever their base can be used.)

Additionally, from just a maintenance perspective, forcing manual override of constructors would make it difficult to reason about future behavior should the base class constructors change, and would entail having to always check, and often modify, any derived classes when new constructors are added to the base. Even a few of these would be problematic; but in cases where there are dozens or more such classes (and derived classes of those classes, etc.), maintenance and QA will quickly become a nightmare.