# Derived constructor with type parameter

Tags: c#

EDIT: added follow up question from getting a solution suggested from another question
EDIT2: I just realised that my follow up question was not needed.

Is it possible to have an abstract base class with a type parameter of T have a constructor that takes a parameter of T and assigns it to a property of T? What i want to achieve is that all derived classes has a constructor that does this?

Something like:

```
 public abstract class NotificationBase <T>
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public T Context { get; set; }


    public NotificationBase(T context, string text)
    {
        Context = context;
        Text = text;
    }
}

public class NumberNotification : NotificationBase<int>{}

public class Program
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var thing = new NumberNotification(10, "Hello!");

    }
}
```

EDIT:
I got a link to another question that explained how to do this which is great. However i have some issues with that. And i dont mean its wrong, if that is the only way to do it then thats how it is. However its not the ideal situation for what im trying to do. I explain. This was the solution:

```
    public class Base
{
    public Base(Parameter p)
    {
        Init(p)
    }

    void Init(Parameter p)
    {
        // common initialisation code
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(Parameter p) : base(p)
    {
 
    }
}
```

..which works great. However it does create two small issues that id like to se if they can be addressed.

1. What i want is to force all classes that derives from the base to pass a T into the constructor so that its mandatory. With this solution, its possible to leave it out.
2. If all classes should do this then it feels redundant to create a constructor to propagate a mandatory parameter.

EDIT: I just realised that demanding a constructor that propagates the type parameter IS what im looking for. I makes sure that the T property gets a value and also allows for other things to happen in the constructor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I inherit constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873343/can-i-inherit-constructors)

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes it does! But it creates another situation so i will update the op. Thanks! 
Also: last weeks all posts have been instantly down voted. Whats up with that? I cant see my question is that bad?

Comment: What does what? Also I didn't down vote.

Comment: @AluanHaddad oh no i did not think you did it. Im just suprised it seems someone is just downvoting everything instantly. I updated the OP with my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, you just need to propagate the constructor chain using the relevant type, and call the ancestor if needed:

```
public class NumberNotification : NotificationBase<int>
{
  public NumberNotification(int context, string text) 
    : base(context, text)
  {
  }
}
```

Without constructor in child class, the instantiation you wrote can't compile because you don't offer a way for the compiler to know what to do.

You can also offer any other constructor needed.

Therefore now this compiles and works:

```
var thing = new NumberNotification(10, "Hello!");
```

[Inheritance And Constructors (C# Corner)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/inheritance-and-constructors-in-c-sharp)

[base (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base)

Answer (score 0):

Define the parameterized constructor for `NumberNotification` class which should invoke the required constructor of `NotificationBase` using `base`

```
public class NumberNotification : NotificationBase<int>
{
    public NumberNotification(int context, string text)
        :base(context, text)
    {
    }
}
```

Now for `NumberNotification` object, context is type of `int` as here `T` is marked as `int` type which Yyou can check using below code:

```
var thing = new NumberNotification(10, "Hello!");
Console.WriteLine(thing.Context.GetType());
```

The above prints the output as `System.Int32`

Check the fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/keufQO